# Primitive root modulo $p$.

Tags: congruences

Let $a$ be an integer and $p$ an odd prime number. Suppose $\bar{a}$ has order $h>1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, how can we show that $$a^{h-1} + a^{h-2} + ... + a + 1\equiv 0\mod p?$$

Comment: I edited your question. Learn to use mathjax if you are planning to ask more questions on this site. People don't like badly asked and poorly edited questions.

Comment: Is h an integer or just any real number greater than 1?

Comment: @MichaelChernick h is order of a modulo p , then h must be the positive integer

Comment: Okay I can buy that.

Comment: This is true only if $a\not\equiv 1\mod p$, unless $h=p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : You have that $$(a-1)(a^{h-1}+a^{h-2}+\dots +1)=a^h-1.$$
Hence $(a-1)(a^{h-1}+a^{h-2}+\dots +1)\mod p=0$.

Comment: how can we eliminate (a-1) or use other method

Comment: Is $(a-1)$ invertbile? How would that help you?

Answer (score 2):

Use the high school factorisation
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+x+1).$$
Note the relation is valid only if $a\not\equiv 1\mod p$.

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted. Ok I have said the same a bit earlier, but it doesn't deserve a downvote for that. +1 to compensate.

Comment: @Mathematician 42: I was writing my answer while you were posting, apparently. I left it because I added a remark on the validity of the relation in the O.P.'s question, but you may as well add it to your own answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: The validity is ok, the order of $a$ is assumed to be different from one.